# DevExpress RepositoryItemComboBox enter text without showing caret

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using `RepositoryItemComboBox` inside a `DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl`. I have very specific requirements for the behavior of the `RepositoryItemComboBox`. One of these is as follows:

- On receiving focus, the combo box should not show caret. It should not highlight (select) the current text.
- On keyboard input, the combo box should not show caret, but should update the edit value.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior with `RepositoryItemComboBox`?

Comment: Are you not describing TextEditStyle = TextEditStyle.DisableTextEditor?

Comment: @MineR : Thanks! Please provide as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for TextEditStyle = TextEditStyle.DisableTextEditor?